# Why is string in MVC route null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following in my RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

The following ActionResult in UsersController:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string userId)
    {
        ManageUserViewModel model = new ManageUserViewModel();
        model.UserId = userId;

        return View(model);
    }
```

And the url is: address/Users/Edit/1c557388-3570-41ad-b7b3-dc53106a908a

This loads the view ok but every time the string userId is always null and I can't seem to work out why, can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

Use as

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
```

You are routing `id` not the `userId`. If you want userId change it to `userId`

For more details, please [**refer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx#routes)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise it was that literal

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `(string userId)` it should be `(string id)` as shown :

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{.....}
```

Your routing parameter is **id** not **userId**.

If you want `userId` as routing parameter then change route as shown :

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{userId}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", userId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**Edit :-**

A Good tutorial on routing is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx) and [here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC)